# Swift : Issue with accessing CFDictionaryRef for ABAddressBookRef

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, abaddressbook

I'v collected contact's address information in ObjC as,

```
ABMultiValueRef addressProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRef, kABPersonAddressProperty);
CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressProperty, 0);
   if(dict)
   {
     NSString *street = (NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey);
   }
```

So, equivalent Swift code would be,

```
let addressProperty : ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(contactRef, kABPersonAddressProperty).takeUnretainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef

    if let dict : CFDictionaryRef = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressProperty, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? CFDictionaryRef
    {
     let street = CFDictionaryGetValue(dict,kABPersonAddressStreetKey)
    // Stuck here, among  CFString!, UnsafePointer<Void>, CFDictionaryRef ...
    }
```

How will I fetch street and other similar information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `NSDictionary` instead? (not tested)

```
if let dict : NSDictionary = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addressProperty, 0).takeUnretainedValue() as? NSDictionary
{
 let street = dict[kABPersonAddressStreetKey]
}
```

Comment: Oh yes it is working, I had fixed it with dict.__conversion(), which is converting CFDictionaryRef to NSDictionary but now I'm going for NSDictionary directly. Thanks